# Loading matrix and list into Scilab environment

Tags: scilab

I am trying to load a matrix and a list into Scilab's environment. The matrix and the list are created by a function(F1).  To do this, I know that the matrix and list are defined as output at the beginning/first line of the function. Then, there is another function, F2 that takes these matrix and list for computation. BUT, it seems that the matrix and list are not loaded into the Scilab's environment. Does F1 not outputting the values or F2 which is not accepting the values?  I'm I doing it correctly? Please help me out. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you are trying to do ?

```
function [a,b]= f1()
         a=rand(2,2);
         b=list(2,"foo");
endfunction

function f2(a,b)
         disp(a)
         disp(b)
endfunction

[a,b]=f1();
f2(a,b);
```

Comment: Thanks Sylvestre. For the last two lines: [a,b]=f1() and f2(a,b) - where should I execute them?

Comment: In the Scilab console or in your script ?!